# IHP - What all does`ihp-app-to-docker-image` command do?

Tags: ihp

I generated a docker image for my IHP Pro app with `ihp-app-to-docker-image` as shown in the [documentation](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/deployment.html#deployment).

Is this image production ready or do we have to update `Config.hs` as shown under [Deploying on Bare Metal](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/deployment.html#deploying-on-bare-metal) and then generate the docker image.